# Passing parameters from R Markdown to Latex

Tags: parameters, latex, r-markdown

Good evening,
I would like to pass custom parameters from Rmd to the header (using fancyhdr) of a pdf document.
I tried the code below, but I don't know how it could interpret \parames$figureno ... and I get that error when knitting:

```
 ! Undefined control sequence.
\f@nch@och ->\parames 
                      $figureno\strut 
l.169 \end{document}
```

Here is the code in Rmd:

```
output: 
pdf_document:
  keep_tex: true
  includes:
      in_header: header.tex
params:
  figureno: "Fig. 1-1"
```

And the header.tex:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\parames$figureno}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{And this is a fancy footer}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand\headrule{%
       \vspace{3pt}
       \hrulefill}
```

How can I make it working ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This does not work that way. `params$figureno` would be available in your R chunks. What you can do is to alter the default tex template and directly add your code (from `header.tex`) to the template preamble. Then you include this template via the YAML `template:` parameter and add `figureno: "Fig. 1-1"` to the YAML (without `params:`). The corresponding line in your `fancyhdr`code would then be `\fancyhead[CO,CE]{$figureno$}` where `$figureno$` is a pandoc variable.

Comment: I tried it, and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the solution proposed by Martin Schmelzer (above). With the advantage that I can still include another *.tex to design the header with static content.

```
---
template: default-1.17.0.2.tex
title: "Some test..."
figureno: "Fig. 1-1"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
    keep_tex: true

---
```

I inserted these two lines in the main template (default-1.17.0.2.tex):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{$figureno$}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can sort of do this, but it's tricky.  A way that works is to put all of `header.tex` into the `header-includes:` field of the YAML header.  (Unfortunately, you can't have both `header-includes:` and `includes: in_header`.)  You can execute R code within strings in the YAML header, 
so that's how you'd get your `\fancyhead` set properly.  For example:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - '`r paste0("\\fancyhead[CO,CE]{", params$figureno, "}")`'
  - \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{And this is a fancy footer}
  - \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  - \renewcommand\headrule{\vspace{3pt}\hrulefill}
params:
  figureno: "Fig. 1-1"
---
```

Note that backslashes need to be doubled in the R code `paste0("\\fancyhead[CO,CE]{", params$figureno, "}")` to end up with a single backslash in the result.

Also note that the R code needs to be inline R code wrapped in backticks *and then also* wrapped in quotes as a string constant.  I've seen recommendations that single quotes be used on the string constant instead of double quotes, but I don't know if that really matters.

Comment: What a delightfully detailed and useful answer! I would add for future others that this means there's extra escaping with \ needed. I kept missing the double \ in `\\fancyhead` at first. And then when I wanted to add a newline in my footer with using this solution, I had to use \\\\. Thanks!