# Pass variables from Rmd/YAML header to before_body .tex

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I have a YAML header like this:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    includes:
      in_header: "preamble.tex"
      before_body: "title.tex"
    keep_tex: yes
documentclass: report
classoption:
  - landscape
---
```

And I knit the document with a call to `rmarkdown::render()`.

What I want is to call `render()` like this:

```
rmarkdown::render("MyDocument.Rmd", params = list(
  person1 = "John Doe, JD",
  person2 = "Charlie P. Adams, CPA"
))
```

And they get passed into the Rmd but then further pushed down **into title.tex** (which is included in the YAML header) where something like this would occur:

```
\vspace{15pt}\hspace{15pt}\large [$person1$] \par
\vspace{15pt}\hspace{15pt}\large [$person2$] \par
```

How can I pass the string to, and how do I parse it within, title.tex?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54746683/2777074

Comment: Possibly (I see now how this would work), I'd really like to avoid putting the entire .tex in the header since it is not a small file. I did edit the OP to clarify what I need. Apologies but really the params need to come from the call to render(), where (possibly) they go to the YAML header (or maybe not), and then further down to title.tex.

Comment: That said, I know how I can get params into the header. So I could hack together a solution along these lines I think. If there were a way to do this without including 200 lines of latex directly in the YAML header that would I'd prefer that though..

Comment: Have you tried the same approach with your header file?

Comment: I have a title.tex file, not header file. I just tried putting it in the "before_body:" section without passing params in but I get an error like it expects a file: "File \begin{titlepage} not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99"

Comment: this is not possible at the moment within before_body:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65272123/is-there-a-way-to-directly-pass-latex-code-to-before-body-in-an-rmarkdown-yaml-h

Answer (score 1):

I gather it is not possible to do in the way I am asking currently. So I'm gonna answer with the workaround I came up with: approach is to store some strings in a title_template.tex - instead of $person1$ i settled on `person1` as a safer pattern to use. Then I gsub the file from R like this (adapted from this gist):

```
fin <- "title_template.tex"
fout <- "title.tex"
x <- readLines(fin)

y <- gsub( "`clientname`", "Really Big Client", x ) %>%
  gsub( "`groupname`", "Ministry of Silly Walks", .) %>%
  gsub( "`person1`", "John Doe, JD", . ) %>%
  gsub( "`person2`", "Charlie P. Adams, CPA", . )

cat(y, file=fout, sep="\n")
```

Since I need to do this upon an event in a shiny app, I will put that code in an observeEvent(), the replacement strings coming from textInput in the ui, and the gsub/write out of the new file will occur just prior to the call to rmarkdown::render(fout). Will be sure to overwrite the file each time.